# Соединение с QTcpServer и отправление пакетов

Tags: c++, qt

Только начал изучать программирование сетей, сокетов и тд. Скачал простой сервер [из этой хабра-статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/131472/). В слоте `on_starting_clicked()` заменил строку

```
tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 33333)
```

на

```
tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 33333)
```

и написал простенькую программу, которая должна подключаться к этому серверу и посылать ровно 1 сообщение. Ее код:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication z(argc, argv);
    QTcpSocket a;
    a.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    a.bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 33333);
    a.write(QByteArray("rferfergregerger"));
    return z.exec();
}
```

Проблема в том, что программа не подключается к серверу и ничего на него не отсылает. Вопрос: а как заставить программу отсылать серверу сообщения? Что я делаю не так и как нужно сделать? Что вообще значит `QHostAddress::Any`? Как другим компьютерам подключаться к серверу? Можно ли через сокеты отправлять структуры и если да, то как это сделать используя QTcpSocket?

Comment: А что у вас представляет собой сервер? Его тоже вы пишете? Как вы определили, что сообщение не отсылается? QHostAddress::Any - это широковещательный ip-адрес (255.255.255.255), пакет с таким адресом назначения доставляется всем узлам сети. А QHostAddress::LocalHost - это адрес 127.0.0.1. Если вы пытаетесь отловить пакеты в Wireshark, то вы не увидите пакеты с таким адресом назначения, их простыми средствами не отловить. А если вы в выводе сервера видите, что пакеты не приходят, то надо смотреть код сервера.

Comment: Сервер писал не я, а автор статьи на хабре, ссылку на которую, я оставил в основном посте. При подключении сервер в текстовом поле должен вывести сообщение, что подключился новый клиент, а при получении паке, он должен выводить его в тоже самое текстовое поле. При попытке подключиться к серверу из своей программы у меня не происходит ни первое, ни второе.

Comment: А нет, ошибся насчет [QHostAddress::Any](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhostaddress.html#SpecialAddress-enum). А по вопросу - приложите ещё вывод ipconfig /all.

Comment: Учитывая что Qt кроссплатформеный фреймворк то можно еще и плтформу под которой вы работаете с задачей указать?

Answer (score 2):

Для подключения к серверу используйте метод `connectToHost()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QScopedPointer<QTcpSocket> socket(new QTcpSocket());
    socket->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 33333);
    if(socket->waitForConnected(5000) == false) return -1;

    socket->write("tra-ta-ta");

    return app.exec();
}
```

Обратите внимание на [предупреждение](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForConnected) в справке Qt для метода `QAbstractSocket::waitForConnected()`:

> This function may fail randomly on Windows. Consider using the event
>   loop and the connected() signal if your software will run on Windows.

В Windows для определения факта подключения сокета к серверу надёжнее воспользоваться сигналом `QAbstractSocket::connected()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSharedPointer<QTcpSocket> socket(new QTcpSocket());
    socket->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 33333);

    connect(socket.data(), &QTcpSocket::connected, [socket]() {
        socket->write("tra-ta-ta");
    });

    return app.exec();
}
```